# Query optimization - second opinion

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am looking on a second opinion concerning query optimization.

I run this query a large table (currently 12.000 rows but be lightning fast with 100.000's of records)

```
Select a.user_id
from bf_user_meta a
left outer join bf_user_meta b
on a.meta_value =b.meta_value
where a.meta_key = 'subsectoren'
AND (a.user_id = '13' OR b.user_id = '13')
OR a.meta_key = 'see_subsectoren'
GROUP BY user_id
```

Now this query needs 13 seconds of execution time.

I got indexes on user_id and meta_key

Mysql caching is set on.

My knowledge of join queries is rather low so I'm looking for advice on how to optimize this one.

Comment: What's the first opinion? Also, you have a GROUP BY clause, but ni aggregating functions. Why?

Comment: Can you list the data types, indexes, etc.?

Comment: Are you sure the query is correct?  The self join on the table and lack of conditions on `b` look suspicious.

Comment: meta_id int(20) unsigned

user_id bigint(20) unsigned

meta_key varchar(255)

meta_value text

Suppose the query is correct, untill now I was receiving the results I need.

The purpose of the query is:
When user 1 is looking for all other users in the same 'subsector' their needs to be a list all user_id's where meta_value equals the meta_value of user 1 on the see_subsectoren value of all these users (that's why I got the 'see_subsectoren' in the meta_key column and why I'm not searching for a match 'subsectoren').

Comment: Due to the use of OR in the WHERE clause, MySQL cannot usefully use the indexes on the tables (beyond an index on meta_value to help the join). The solution by Gordon below uses UNIONs,reducing it to several simple queries which can each uses indexes and then merging the results of those simple queries together.

Comment: Can you do a SHOW TABLE so we can see if there are any indexes on the columns?

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
Select a.user_id
from bf_user_meta a left outer join
     bf_user_meta b
     on a.meta_value = b.meta_value
where a.meta_key = 'subsectoren' AND (a.user_id = '13' OR b.user_id = '13') OR
      a.meta_key = 'see_subsectoren'
GROUP BY user_id;
```

This is going to be challenging.  For optimization, I would suggest starting by eliminating the `or`s and using `union` (to remove duplicates):

```
select a.user_id
from bf_user_meta a
where a.meta_key = 'subsectoren' AND a.user_id = '13'
union
select a.user_id
from bf_user_meta a join
     bf_user_meta b
     on a.meta_value = b.meta_value
where a.meta_key = 'subsectoren' AND b.user_id = '13'
union
select
from bf_user_meta a
where a.meta_key = 'see_subsectoren';
```

The best indexes for these are:  `bf_user_meta(meta_key, user_id)` and `bf_user_meta(meta_value, meta_key)` and `bf_user_meta(user_id, meta_value)`.  But you can play with each of the subqueries to optimize them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is very confusing and your explanation to it doesn't really clarify it to me. Are you trying to get the meta value for user 13/'subsectoren' and then select all users with 'see_subsectoren' and the same meta value? That would simply be:

```
select user_id
from bf_user_meta
where meta_value in 
(
  select meta_value
  from bf_user_meta
  where meta_key = 'subsectoren' and user_id = 13
)
and meta_key = 'see_subsectoren';
```

If I misunderpret your explanation then please try again to explain what your query is supposed to do and how the records are related.